# Why are names that begin with "Mc" first in order over names that begin with "Ma"?

Tags: orthography, names, surnames, non-standard, sort-ordering

Why is it that in lists of people’s names, surnames beginning with *Mc*
are listed before surnames beginning with *Ma*?

For example, if a book had a bibliography listing its references, we would
see that *McGann, Anthony* listed first and *Maddox, Graham* second, like this:

> #### References
>
> 1. [McGann, Anthony](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=yA1SWXcAAAAJ&hl=en) ...
> 2. [Maddox, Graham](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=F2jIEmMAAAAJ&hl=en) ...

Why doesn’t the ‹a› in *McGann* come before the ‹d› 
in *Maddox* here? Does capitalization matter?

Even when you search Wikipedia, their pop-up is ordered strangely when you start typing in the search box and get as far as “ian mac”:

[image: wikipedia popup for "ian mac" search]

That order is not what I would expect. Why do they do that? Also, how come they showed me *Ian McKellan* and *Ian McShane* and such when those don’t start with the same letters as those I searched for when I typed “ian mac”?

Does this happen with other 
names more or less like those as well, making names like these appear
in a surprising order as well?

> 3. May, Julian
> 4. Mbombela, Frederica
> 5. McBride, Martina
> 6. Mabrey, Sunny
> 7. Macaluso, Luigi
> 8. Magellan, Ferdinand
> 9. MacGill, James
> 10. Mack, Sennett
> 11. McGill, Jason
> 12. McKinley, William
> 13. Mackerel, Jack
> 14. Machado, Antonio
> 15. Machiavelli, Niccolò
> 16. Ma, Yo-Yo

Comment: Perhaps the sorting is done on the basis of first name. Anthony comes before Graham.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija Not so. In that case, the names would be listed with the first name first: *Anthony McGann*, *Graham Maddox*.

Comment: McNames are generally sorted as if they are spelled Mac - because if you're verbally advised to call "McDonald", you might not know which way the name is spelled, so it's handy to have them all sorted together.

Answer (score 25):

The usual convention in the UK, in telephone directories etc is that Scottish surnames starting Mc are, for alphabetical purposes, treated as though there were an invisible a, between the M and the c. Thus our own telephone directory proceeds as McDonald, J.A., MacDonald J.C., McDonald J.M., MacDonald K. etc.

Comment: -1 What is an "invisible *a*"? Why is such a convention needed? Is there an "invisible" motive behind it? Is the phenomenon a quirk of the telephone directories, or is that more pervasive?

Comment: @Kris So you downvote me on account of the practices of directory compilers? As anyone who has a surname starting Mc (which is only an abbreviation of Mac) will tell you, they regularly receive mail addressed both ways. No one other than close friends and relatives ever remember. Whenever I send a Christmas card to my Scottish GP I always have to check (even after 28 years) whether his name starts Mc or Mac. So it seems reasonable enough for a directory compiler to treat all instances of 'Mc' as if they were 'Mac'. But I don't know why I am having to defend people who compile directories.

Comment: That counts as a great and useful comment, though not an answer.

Comment: @Kris There is a Wiki entry on the very subject of the alpabetisation of Mc and Mac.

Comment: Please cite it if you think it provides a canonical answer.

Comment: @Kris I shall avoid the pettiness of down voting your own answer, but I note that it provides less information yet says substantially the same thing as mine. And that's the last I have to say on the matter.

Comment: I heard of this convention in school long ago.  But (living in the US) I have never seen it applied.

Comment: @Kris: You ask if the phemomenon is a 'quirk of the telephone directories' or if it's more pervasive. In my experience, it's more pervasive. I work with law books, and each of them contains an alphabetical list of judicial cases referred to in that book. The 'M' section of the one in front of me reads 'M v United Kingdom, McCool v ..., McDonald v ..., MacDonald v... , McIntyre v ..., Mackley v..., McKerry v ...' etc. Similarly, in the index to the books, 'Mc/Mac' comes before (for instance) 'magistrates court'. So I think it's fair to say that it's an indexing convention too.

Comment: Upvoted because good answer and ... Kris. Yeah.

Comment: Good answer and I am glad you gave the UK context.  Living in the US, it seems more unusual to do so perhaps than the UK.  Also, as a computer programmer (writing sorting algorithms), it is something that introduces an extra bit of complexity.   Maybe librarians know about this, but my computer needs to be told it.

Comment: [1/2] A comment on WS2 and @Kris' discussion: it seemed to me Kris was simply saying that your answer is incomplete. The OP asks why McNames are sorted the way they are. You answer by saying it's a convention, in UK telephone dictionaries. That answer is incomplete in two ways. Firstly, saying "it's convention" to a "why" question is usually incomplete. Sometimes, conventions are completely arbitrary; they are the convention because something needs to be. In this case however, there's a reason behind the convention, and you fail to give that reason within your answer.

Comment: [2/2] Secondly, "UK phone directories" is not general. OP's question is general. Your example of this convention being used is helpful, but your answer does not give any info as to whether what you said applies elsewhere. All that I just said here, I believe is contained in Kris' comment; "Why is such a convention needed? Is there an "invisible" motive behind it? Is the phenomenon a quirk of the telephone directories, or is that more pervasive?" If this is not the case, please correct me @Kris. To conclude, I think you were dismissive of very valid criticism that could've improved you answer.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, it is because of treating *Mc* and *Mac* as identical.

Naturally then, *Mac* occurs **before** *Maddox*.

It's as such not a sorting issue but a lexical one.

Answer (score 2):

Practise varies between cultures, and between organisations within those cultures.

Some take surnames strictly alphabetically, so Makespeare would come before Mcdonald.

Others (as in your example) treat Mc as an abbreviation of Mac, thus putting Mcdonald before Maddox.

See wikipedia on this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order).

Comment: Seconds apart! Agree with you.

Comment: All I can speak for is the UK telephone directory convention which places McDonald before Maddox.

Comment: Practise also varies depending on software.